# Django admin queryset foreign key to user django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-allauth

I have an `e-commerce` development and I'm looking to send an `email` to the client from the `admin` site, I can´t the `queryset` correclty to do this. I have the following model:

**models.py:**

```
class Orden(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Usuario')
    productos = models.ManyToManyField(OrdenProducto)
    fecha_orden = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completada = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    id_transaccion = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    correo_enviado = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    datos_pedido = models.ForeignKey(
        'DatosPedido', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    pago = models.ForeignKey(
        'Pago', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    cupon = models.ForeignKey(
        'Cupon', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Orden"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cliente.username
```

`cliente` has a foreign key to the `User` model and I want to get the `email` address, I have tried many ways but I just can´t get it.

**admin.py**:

```
class OrdenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('cliente', 'completada', 'correo_enviado')
    actions = ['enviar_correo']

    def enviar_correo(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(correo_enviado=True)
        a = queryset.get(cliente=self.user.email)

        send_mail('test', 'test', 'xxxxxx@mail.com',
                  ['a], fail_silently=True)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the user from the logged user in the admin?
If it is the case, you can use 
request.user.email instead of self.user.email

Comment: no, I'm trying to get the email from the client, which is the one that made the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try iterating the queryset to access the specific data in the rows.

Try the following code.

```
class OrdenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('cliente', 'completada', 'correo_enviado')
    actions = ['enviar_correo']

    def enviar_correo(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(correo_enviado=True)
        for obj in queryset:
            email = obj.cliente.email

        send_mail('test', 'test', email,
                  ['a], fail_silently=True)
```

I hope this code helps you

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have extended the default user model or have created Your Own user model, django default user model does not have an email field.

So if you have extended or created Your Own model you can do

```
myordenobj.cliente.email
```

But if you're using the default user model and your username is an email then do.

```
myordenobj.cliente.username
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using Django-allauth, it has an email field, forgot to point that out

Comment: I have tried the following: a = queryset.cliente.email and I'm getting an error that says: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'cliente'

Comment: Oh I missed that... It's a queryset. You have to loop over it.